# If an int is 32 bits. Where are functions like ToString() and GetType() stored?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

An int is 32 bits. All those bits are used to store an int value. Why can an int also contain functions like ToString() and GetType()?

Comment: Could be for equivalent string representation of it and getting it's type information?

Comment: It would be a horrible language if every instance contained a copy of its methods!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whilst you're treating an `int` as an `int`, the system knows *exactly* what type it's dealing with and can go directly to the methods. As soon as you need to use an `int` in a more ambiguous situation (where the type of the object is unknown), you have to [*box*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx) the `int` into an `object`.

At that point, the box contains not just the actual data for the `int` but also the usual things associated with reference types - such as the reference to the `Type` to allow methods to be found.

This same theory applies to all value types - whilst it's stored in a variable of the correct type, the *exact* type is known. This is why value types cannot inherit or be inherited from - so that the type of the *variable* (field, etc) informs the system of the exact type to use, and from the type, the methods.

Answer (score 5):

The functions themselves are pointed to by a method table. When calling a virtual function on a struct, the struct is first boxed to create an object on the heap with an object header. One of the fields of the header points into the method table and the method to call can be looked up from there.

If the struct type overrides the virtual methods in question then the boxing can be avoided since the location of the method can be determined statically.

Answer (score 0):

In C# int and every other object derives from `object` type, which contains those methods. It doesn't matter how much memory it needs to allocate. These are the most basics of c# and I suggest you reading any C# book or at least turorial befor asking questions here.

Comment: Unfortunately, `int` doesn't derive from `object`. You can see its [definition here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.aspx).

Comment: It does, same as every other value type.

Comment: Every CLR type except for interfaces, unmanaged pointers and System.Object itself implicitly derives from System.Object.

Comment: @Tarec what you say is true, but you completely miss the point of the question. "Derives" is logical concept, it doesn't mean that all the derivatives of the object are internally implemented the same way. `int` is actually just 4 bytes region of memory, when you call methods on it directly (no boxing) compiler treats it in special way so that `int` looks like it is first class object.

Comment: @Andrey The fact that I didn't explained those differences doesn't mean I'm unaware of them. Yes, it's implemented explicitly in CLR, but - as you said - it is logically still an inheritance. Dropping boxing out of our equation make underlying implementation irrelevant - value types are objects too.

Comment: @Tarec the difference were basically the point of the question. The OP asked how basically int can be 32 bit value and object at the same time

Comment: -1: For missing the point of the question and being patronizing.